# CreateAsync in User Manager - dispose method always called

Tags: c#, asp.net, oauth-2.0, asp.net-identity, idisposable

I am using the Asp.Net identity system but have run in to a problem with the Register method, specifically this line:

```
IdentityResult result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
```

the full method is

```
[ActionName("Register")]
[AcceptVerbs("GET", "POST")]
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Register(RegisterBindingModel model)
{
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        var user = new ApplicationUser() {UserName = model.Email, Email = model.Email};

        IdentityResult result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);

        if (!result.Succeeded)
        {
            return GetErrorResult(result);
        }

        return Ok();
}
```

**I never get a "result", instead the `Dispose()` method is always hit**

```
protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
{
   if (disposing && _userManager != null)
   {
     _userManager.Dispose();
      _userManager = null;
   }
   base.Dispose(disposing);
}
```

what am I missing?

Comment: please show us the full code

Comment: I suposse you are using Entity Framework. Have you created a migration for create/update the database?

Answer (score 0):

I used Code-First in my web app, I was trying to customize Identity's ApplicationUser and I forgot to Remove or update my database after adding Relations in Identity's ApplicationUser class. 
So, what I actually did was sth like this

```
 public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    [Required()]
    public string FullName { get; set; }
    public byte[] UserPhoto { get; set; }

    public virtual List<Class> Classes { get; set; }

    public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager)
    {
        // Note the authenticationType must match the one defined in CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
        var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
        // Add custom user claims here
        return userIdentity;
    }
}
```

I changed it to

```
     public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    [Required()]
    public string FullName { get; set; }
    public byte[] UserPhoto { get; set; }

    //public virtual List<Class> Classes { get; set; }

    public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager)
    {
        // Note the authenticationType must match the one defined in CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
        var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
        // Add custom user claims here
        return userIdentity;
    }
}
```